# Why is DEFAULT Keyword Allowed in CREATE PROCEDURE Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following statement, the DEFAULT keyword appears where a default value is defined for a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test
    @sp_param1 varchar(20) = DEFAULT
AS
    SELECT @sp_param1 AS myTest
;
```

NULL is assigned to @sp_param1.  But, [The default value must be a constant or the NULL keyword.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Why is the DEFAULT keyword allowed in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The DEFAULT keyword is a placeholder for something that you want to provide, but is not really even NULL.  Most commonly seen in

```
exec SProcName 2, DEFAULT
```

Even though the 2nd param is supplied, it is not actually a value, but is an instruction to use the DEFAULT value of the 2nd param.

When used in the CREATE PROC itself, it parses, but is simply treated as NULL.

Comment: do you know why the CREATE PROC parses?  What value is gained by allowing DEFAULT to place in the CREATE PROC?

Comment: @bobs - it is another syntax to say, `this column is optional` without actually giving it an explicit NULL value.

Comment: Future proofing, perhaps? i.e. allowing for a type for which the default is something other than `NULL`? For a table-value parameter, the default is an empty table but then again you can't use the keyword `DEFAULT` with a table-value parameter!